# Erratic behavior retrieving large data (several tens of gigabytes) that has been serialized by Mathematica

Tags: export, import, memory, sparse-arrays

Hardware: PC with 256GB RAM

OS: Windows 10

Mathematica: Version 13.0.1

One of my projects has led to the creation of a SparseArray whose ByteCount is ~ 35GB in RAM.  At the time of creation the SparseArray is functional and returns information when appropriately queried.

When I Export the SparseArray using the .mx format, the data stores on my hard drive with a memory footprint of ~ 17GB.  No errors are generated.

When I attempt to Import the same SparseArray using a fresh kernel, the computer spins for about 2 minutes - during this time I see RAM spike to roughly 90GB, and then slowly the RAM usages drops and the kernel just quits.  I hear a beep - no error messages are generated, and I can't retrieve my data.

I wish I could say this behavior has not been seen before, but while working in Mathematica v12, I attempted to use BinarySerialize to store a large Association - only to discover I couldn't retrieve it either.  Attempts to get help from Wolfram tech support were fruitless as they claimed they didn't have access to a machine with enough RAM to explore the problem. Sigh.

Questions I can't help but ponder:

1. Has anyone else noticed such erratic behavior trying to retrieve serialized data from Mathematica?  (I seem to notice the behavior when the ByteCount of the object reaches a few tens of gigabytes in size.)
2. Any advice for resolving this?  Avoiding BinarySerialize and mx formats and sticking with Put/Get does seem to work, but then my read/write times are glacially slow.  Almost a deal breaker kind of slow.

Finally, if there are any adventurous souls with sufficient hardware, here is a link to my SparseArray object. (Will it load on your computer without quitting the kernel?)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2hk2e6ubbi8ivuq/InformativeKmersSparseArray-A.mx?dl=0

If by some miracle you get it to load, the following should be a successful query: (assuming you store the SparseArray in a variable called "data".)

data[[2322312231212121]]

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Can you share the code used to  serialize the matrix.  Sounds like it might have unpacked from `SparseArray` during serialization.

Comment: @Edmund   Based on your suggestion, I tried setting On["Packing"] before importing the SparseArray and no warnings were generated.  As far as the serialization code you mention, I am relying on the internal code of Export that understands MX files.  I am not doing anything outside of that to provide additional serialization.  The literal command is: Export["InformativeKmersSparseArray.mx", informativeKmersSparseArray];  If this is an undetectable unpacking issue, I may need to resort to storing the components needed to build the SparseArray and recreate on the fly....  Thanks!

Comment: You could try [`DumpSave`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave.html) instead of `Export`.

Comment: I was able to import without any issues, [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMiKE.png).  Mma 13.0.1 on Win 10.  Maybe restart your kernel or session.

Comment: @Edmund   Thank you and wow!  This is the first evidence I have that the problem is unique to my hardware/software.  I have tried restarting the kernel and rebooting the machine many times.  I guess I can try resetting Mathematica and reinstalling it.  I have a bit of a sinking feeling.....

Comment: Might be a RAM issue.  Try running a memory checker.  Do you have ECC RAM?  I only have 128GB non-ECC; half of what you have but it worked fine.

Comment: FYI - I tried exporting it to some of the matrix formats. ["MTX"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MTX.html) and ["HarwellBoeing"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HarwellBoeing.html) would not take it because it is a vector not a matrix. ["MAT'](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MAT.html) just crashed the kernel.